# Select Months This Year MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to show all this year months (until today month). For example, this is my desired result:

```
MONTHS
Jan
Feb
Mar
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks..

Comment: Why do you need MySQL to do this? Won't any programming language do? What MySQL version?

Comment: I need this because I want to summarize total production by month. I want to show all months total production regardless if the production result is 0. I'm using mysql 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following leaves a month (as 1-12) that you can join against other fields:

```
SELECT month, MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-01-01'), INTERVAL month-1 MONTH)) as name_of_month
FROM (SELECT 1 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 5 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 7 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 8 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 9 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 10 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 11 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 12 month) m
 WHERE month <= MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. thank you. appreciate this so much!

Answer (score 1):

While this is quite trivial in a programming language kind be a bit complex when attempting with mysql.

You can look at the live code run here. https://paiza.io/projects/zcABYyyM_uu3r2LX7cCmfQ

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_months_upto_current_month()
BEGIN
    DECLARE month  INT;
    DECLARE inter  INT;
    DECLARE result  VARCHAR(25);

    DECLARE current_month  INT;

    SET month = 1;
    SET current_month = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE());

    WHILE month  <= current_month DO
        SET inter = current_month-month;
        SET result = MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL inter MONTH));
        SELECT SUBSTRING(result,1,3); -- to truncate to 3 letter months
        SET month = month + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;


CALL generate_months_upto_current_month();
```

Since I am using loops I had to use a stored procedure. I have mainly used mysql date functions to sort out the date interactions.

Have a look at the following resource for details on [Date functions](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/date-and-time-functions.php)

Comment: your procedure is interesting. how can I use procedure created in my select statement?

Comment: You will have to insert the result into a temporary table. I think @danblack's answer is a far better alternative. :)